# Using Volley to Parse an array from PHP into Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-volley

I am unable to find any resources about parsing an array into my android application from PHP. I am using Volley to handle the connection.

At the moment I have an array in the PHP script on the web server containing connections to a database which puts the data from MySQL query into the array.

```
$latitude = array (
    //Code for array here
);

$longitude = array (
    //Code for array here
);
```

I am able to connect to the script okay but cannot get figure out how to get each element from the array in PHP to an array in my **mainActivity.java** file.

The Java code is throwing an exception saying 'No value for Latitude'
The way I understand this is because 'latitude' also tried '$latitude' is not the name of the array it is the variable name. In PHP I don't think there is such a name.

Is there another way to parse the contents of this array to Java.
The Java code I have tried is:

```
String url = "urlHere";
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, jObj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("$latitude");
                        //Loop through array
                        for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject locationItem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String latitude = locationItem.getString("index1");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Error encountered.
                        //Log Error
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: is the array inside a json object? Because if it isn't you need to use JsonArrayRequest rather than JsonObjectRequest. Could you post the json response that you are receiving from the server?

Comment: It is picking up the contents, anyway it says: **com.android.volley.parseError: org.json.JSONEXCEPTION:Value("latitude":{"index1":100", "index2","200"}) of type org.json.JSONOBJECT cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Oh no wonder, let me write an answer

Comment: Please remove the $ from "$latitude", shouldn't be there since the JSON key is "latitude" not "$latitude" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason your getting an error is because

```
"latitude":
{
     "index1": "100", 
     "index2": "200",
}
```

should be (**in order to get your code to work**):

```
"latitude": [
         { "index1": "100" },
         { "index2": "200" },
]
```

1. In the original JSON, you've just got a JSON object with keys that are named `index1` and `index2`.
2. In the second JSON, you've got an array of JSON objects with `index1` as a key in the first element and `index2` in the second element.

**UPDATE:**
Even though the above will get your code to *work*. I recommend that you change the JSON to:

```
"latitude": [
    "100",
    "200",
]
```

and for your `onResponse(...)` method write:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("latitude");
        //Loop through array
        for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            String latitude = jsonArray.getString(i);
        }
    }
    // Rest of your code can stay the same
}
```

Seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: Hey mate, have upvoted your answer but I had to re-write Java using ArrayRequest. I did employ some of the tips for PHP above. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped you out :)